# why doesn't spring-boot listen to the logging.path variable?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Using spring-boot 1.2.3.RELEASE.

The only way I can get spring-boot to log to a specific directory is by setting the "log.file" property like so:

```
logging.file=/var/log/app.log
```

But as far as I can tell, [according to the docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html), I should be doing:

```
logging.file=app.log
logging.path=/var/log
```

But it just doesn't seem to listen to the logging.path property, it will just write the file to the current directory.

Are the docs wrong or is there something really obvious I'm missing here?

Also, with this setting, it's still going to do log rolling properly, right?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

From the documentation:

> If you want to write log files in addition to the console output you
>   need to set a logging.file or logging.path property

Spring boot considers either `file` or `path` property, not both.

This [page](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-logging-file-output) has all combinations of `file` and `path` properties.

Comment: ...but why wouldn't we be able to change the file name AND path?

Comment: This is very un-intuitive and the confusion is only furthered by the documentation which insinuates both approaches work in unison by stating `The following table shows how the logging.* properties can be used together`

Comment: @McNinja: when specifying the logging.file you can give a path + filename too, not only the filename.

Comment: `logging.path` is deprecated now. Spring introduced `logging.file.path` to avoid confusion

Answer (score 6):

Variables `path` and `file` can be used simultaneously in the following ways (**application.yml**):

```
logging:
  path: /var/log/
  file: ${logging.path}app.log
```

As a result, spring-boot will keep a log in the file `/var/log/app.log`

Answer (score 3):

using spring 2.4.5

this is work

```
logging.file.path=./log/
logging.file.name=${logging.file.path}mylog.txt
```

or

```
logging.file.name=./log2/mylog.txt
```

in summary

```
logging.file.path=.             # write logs to the current directory
logging.file.path=/home/logs    # write logs to /home/logs
logging.file.path=/mnt/logdir   # write logs to /mnt/logdir
```

for Spring Boot 1.x : set logging.path

Answer (score 1):

In application.properties, just use the below variable

```
logging.file.path={--your file path--}
```